# OpenSSH artifacts, remote system access?

Tags: ssh, attack-prevention, file-access, openssh

After stumbling upon some unknown folders in my unused OneDrive ([posted question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/239723/unknown-folders-in-onedrive)), I did some digging arround and found some interesting logs. Apparently, OpenSSH had been used for remote access on my machine. A description of the attack can be here https://az4n6.blogspot.com/2020/02/detecting-laterial-movment-with-winscp.html.

I did a comparison and found out that the log information was indeed an outlier. There were 1450 audit failures in the past 7 days with various account name attempts. And it gets worse, judging by the audit successes and OpenSSH operational logs, there were multiple sucessful connections via the sshd process from various adresses, all over the world.

I think there is now little room for doubt whether unauthorized remote access did take place. The question rather is, what can be done after the fact. I stopped and disabled the sshd-service, which seems prevented further remote access according to the event logs.

How should one proceed to ensure complete system sanitization in this case?

**Example from audit successes.**

> SubjectUserName COMPUTERNAME
> SubjectDomainName WORKGROUP 
> SubjectLogonId 0x3e7 
> LogonGuid {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
> TargetUserName sshd_1660 
> TargetDomainName VIRTUAL USERS 
> TargetLogonGuid {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
> TargetServerName localhost 
> TargetInfo localhost 
> ProcessId 0x67c 
> ProcessName C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd.exe 
> IpAddress - 
> IpPort -

> SubjectUserName COMPUTERNAME
> SubjectDomainName WORKGROUP 
> SubjectLogonId 0x3e7 
> LogonGuid {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
> TargetUserName sshd_1336 
> TargetDomainName VIRTUAL USERS 
> TargetLogonGuid {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
> TargetServerName localhost 
> TargetInfo localhost 
> ProcessId 0x538 
> ProcessName C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd.exe 
> IpAddress - 
> IpPort -

**Examples from OpenSSH Operational logs.**

> EventData
>
> process sshd 
> payload Disconnected from 45.67.14.20 port 43576 [preauth]

> EventData
>
> process sshd 
> payload Received disconnect from 45.67.14.20 port 49506:11: Bye Bye [preauth]

> EventData
>
> process sshd 
> payload Did not receive identification string from 139.162.75.112 port 56876

> EventData
>
> process sshd 
> payload Received disconnect from 222.186.15.115 port 20660:11: [preauth]

> EventData
>
> process sshd 
> Connection closed by 70.57.111.62 port 42988 [preauth]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server), [Advice on what to do after being hacked?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23842/advice-on-what-to-do-after-being-hacked).

Comment: I don't know how to interpret the Windows logs, but the OpenSSH logs don't seem to indicate any successful logins.

Comment: Does "[preauth]" mean there was connection but no authentication?